# What happens to the unused packages after an ISO install?

Tags: linux, installation, centos, iso-image, redhat-enterprise-linux

I am making a Red Hat ISO that boots off a kickstart configuration file. To do this, I have been following [these instructions over at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/517908/how-to-create-a-custom-iso-image-in-centos).

The ISO that I want to edit, which will eventually become my customized ISO, I download from Red Hat and mount. From there I make changes etc. I noticed that in the Packages folder of the ISO there are 5000+ packages, however I wish to only perform a minimal install plus a few additional packages totaling about 400 packages.

After the install happens, are the other ~4,600 packages deleted or are they always going to be sitting somewhere in my system?

Further, if I know what I want in my ISO, is it a good idea to delete the extraneous packages from the ISO? Is this as simple as just removing them from the Packages directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a good idea to delete the packages from the ISO, unless you have totally analyzed
all possible dependencies. I would rather suggest to look for minimal Linux
distributions that have all the software you need (unless Red Hat is dictated).

In any case, uninstalled packages do not take up space on the disk.
This is why when installing additional packages you must either have the ISO mounted
or an Internet connection to the repository, to be able to get the packages
from some source.